# computed.alias to model doesn't work in Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got a `base` route which loads all categories as the model like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  // retrieve all categories as they are needed in several places
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('category');
  }
})
```

Then there's a `sidebar` (`base.sidebar`) which is supposed to use the model from `base`. The controller looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['base'],
  categories: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.base.model'),
});
```

However this doesn't work anymore as of Ember 2.0. `categories` is just empty.

Which deprecation did I miss?

Comment: If `base.sidebar` is a nested route of `base` and you did not define a model hook for `base.sidebar` route, then you should be able to get parent model from `sidebar` controller via `this.model`. I don't know if it is documented somewhere, I found it by accident.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it either. There is one drawback to this method though. If one day I'll decide to pass `sidebar` its own model it won't work anymore so I prefer GJK's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `controller.needs` property was deprecated in 1.13 and removed in 2.0. You can read [this guide](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_controller-needs) to see how to replace the functionality. For you it'll look something like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    base: Ember.inject.controller(),
    categories: Ember.computed.alias('base.model')
});
```

Comment: As usual thanks a lot, GJK. If it weren't for you I'd probably still not have released my own blog. I must've skipped over this when reading the deprecation guide.

Comment: You're welcome. :) And yeah, the deprecation guide was _really_ long, especially for 1.13, so I don't blame you for missing a few things. I find myself constantly looking back at it. :/